# Use webcomponents in existing ASP.NET WebForms application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-component

I have an large existing ASP.NET WebForms application. This application has a masterpage who manager security, navigation, ...
Pages developped are in a ContentPlaceHolder.

I would like to develop new pages in JS with web components. To use a web component on a page, it must be imported (`<link rel="import" href="...">`). This import must be on the `<head>` part of the page. In my case, the `<head>` is on the master page. So I have to import all the existing web components in the master page to be able to use them.

It does not sound like a very good idea.

How can I do it otherwise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asp.Net lets you place ContentPlaceHolder in head tag. You can load the web components required by the page instead of loading them all in Master Page.

Master Page

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpBody" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web Form

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpHead" runat="server">
    <link rel="import" href="...">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpBody" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Your HTML will look like

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="..." rel="import">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course ! I'm ashamed... Sorry for this stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use `RegisterClientScriptInclude`. This will add the script file to the top of the page, but not in the `<head>`.

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("myScript", "myJavaScriptFile.js");
```

If you really want it in the `<head>` you need to use a `HtmlGenericControl`

```
HtmlGenericControl genericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
genericControl.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
genericControl.Attributes.Add("src", "myJavaScriptFile.js");
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(genericControl);
```

It does not matter where you place this code (Master, Page, User Control). Aspnet will ensure they end up in the right place client side.